# jplayer module conflicts with viewscarousel module

Tags: javascript

When i have turned on a block with viewscarousel and a jplayer inside my page (node/5) it looks like js is conflicting because both of them is stopping to work...

You can take a look at http://hypatia.kz/node/5
When on main page carousel works well, but when jplayer is here - it's not working. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounds like a bug that should be filed on Jplayer's issue queue...

Comment: What would you advice to me?

Comment: You should file a bug on the issue queue.  Describe exactly the steps to take to reproduce the problem.